# How to unit test with actual HttpURLConnection in android?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, httpsurlconnection

I am writing unit tests/integration tests that invoke class library that uses `HttpsURLConnection` objects. Many times whilst invoking methods on the connection objects through the unit tests, like `addRequestProperty`, `setDoOutput`, `setRequestMethod` I get exceptions like `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already connected`. The behaviour is most likely due to following in the gradle as default values are returned.

```
testOptions {
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
}
```

See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support for more details

The same code works fine in the App. Is there a way to actually use the real HttpsURLConnection object while testing?

Comment: It looks like I have to write the test cases as described at http://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests.html as HttpsURLConnection is part of android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since HttpsURLConnection is part of android one way to test would be using `Android Instrumented Tests` as described at http://developer.android.com/training/testing/start/index.html. This starts an AVD or a real device and runs tests there.

Make sure you set the permission in AndroidManifest.xml

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

Answer (score 1):

You can use libraries to mock requests and responses. I recommend this one: [MockWebServer](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver).

**Edit**:
After re-reading your question, it looks like you want to use HttpsURLConnection in your unit tests. The problem of trying to use a class from the Android SDK in your Unit test means that your test becomes an instrumentation test, and that means that it must run on the device/emulator.

If you want an example of integration instrumentation tests, take a look at [this](https://github.com/artem-zinnatullin/qualitymatters/blob/master/app/src/integrationTests/java/com/artemzin/qualitymatters/integration_tests/api/QualityMattersRestApiIntegrationTest.java) great example.

As HttpsURLConnection is also in the Java JDK bundle, if you use that class (import javax.net.ssl) you may have a change of not using any Android classes so you could run your test as a local unit test in your JVM (not the device/emulator).

If you want to understand a bit better the difference between instrumented and local unit tests, read [this](https://medium.com/@yair.kukielka/android-unit-tests-explained-219b04dc55b5#.lnd7029s0) blog post.

Comment: The idea is to do integration tests with the real servers.